# Create a tally/score (of mysql database entires), based on form selection

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a small mysql table, like this:

```
ID  Name    Age Address                  Car       Language      Nights    Student
1   Jim     39  12 High Street, London    1           1            1         1
2   Fred    29  13 High Street, London    1           1            1         0
3   Bill    19  14 High Street, London    1           1            0         0
4   Tom     39  15 High Street, London    1           0            0         0
5   Cathy   29  16 High Street, London    1           0            0         1
6   Petra   19  17 High Street, London    1           0            1         0
7   Heide   39  18 High Street, London    1           1            0         0
8   William 29  19 High Street, London    1           1            0         1
9   Ted     19  20 High Street, London    0           0            0         1
10  Mike    19  21 High Street, London    1           0            0         1
11  Jo      19  22 High Street, London    0           1            0         1
```

This is my PHP page:

```
    <?php 
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=researchdatabase', 'user', 'pass');
  $select = 'SELECT *';
  $from = ' FROM workers';
  $where = ' WHERE TRUE';
  $opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

  if (in_array("hasCar", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND hasCar = 1";
  }

  if (in_array("speaksForeignLanguage", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND speaksForeignLanguage = 1";
  }

  if (in_array("canWorkNights", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND canWorkNights = 1";
  }

  if (in_array("isStudent", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND isStudent = 1";
  }

  if (in_array("MinimumAge", $opts)){
      $where .= " AND age > '**value from html page**'";
  }

  $sql = $select . $from . $where;
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($results);
  echo($json);
?>
```

This is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX filter demo</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      h1 {
          margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
          color: #343434;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-family: 'Ultra', sans-serif;   
          font-size: 36px;
          line-height: 42px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          text-shadow: 0 2px white, 0 3px #777;
      }

      h2 {
          margin: 1em 0 0.3em 0;
          color: #343434;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 30px;
          line-height: 40px;
          font-family: 'Orienta', sans-serif;
      }

      #employees {
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 15px 25px 0 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        width: 700px;
      }

      #employees th {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #039;
        padding: 10px 8px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
      }

      #employees td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        color: #669;
        padding: 8px 10px;
      }

      #employees tbody tr:hover td {
        color: #009;
      }

      #filter {
        float:left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>Temporary worker database</h1>

    <table id="employees">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Car</th>
          <th>Language</th>
          <th>Nights</th>
          <th>Student</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="filter">
      <h2>Filter options</h2>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="car" name="hasCar">
        <label for="car">Has own car</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="language" name="speaksForeignLanguage">
        <label for="language">Can speak foreign language</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nights" name="canWorkNights">
        <label for="nights">Can work nights</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="student" name="isStudent">
        <label for="student">Is a student</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="MinimumAge" onInput="return checkInp()">
        <label for="age">Minimum Age</label>      
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script>
    function checkInp()
    {
      var x=document.getElementById("age").value;
      if (isNaN(x)) 
      {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
      }
    }

      function makeTable(data){
       var tbl_body = "";
          $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "";
            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
              tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            })
            tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
          })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
        var opts = [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
          if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.name);
          }
        });

        return opts;
      }

      function updateEmployees(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
          }
        });
      }

      var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox" || "input:text");
      $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
        updateEmployees(opts);
      });

      updateEmployees();
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The checkboxes remove/hide the students whose criteria does not fit which is checked.

Instead, what I am looking to do is create a new column in the table labelled "score", whereby each student starts off on 0 and as each checkbox is checked, the score goes up by 10. E.g.if you check "Car", Jim, Fred, Bill, Tom get a new score of 10 and this is displayed in the table. The other students (who don't have a car) remain on 0. If Car and Language are ticked, Jim's score becomes 20 (because he has a car & speaks a foreingn language), Fred's score becomes 20 , Jo's score becomes 10 etc...

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to add the score to the HTML table or to the database table?

Comment: (car + language + student + nights) * 10 ?

Comment: sn00k4h - I want to add it to the HTML table

Comment: Strawberry - kind of like that, however, that would only be correct if all 4 checkboxes were checked

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = array_intersect(array("hasCar", "speaksForeignLanguage", "canWorkNights", "isStudent"), $opts);

$select .= ", (" . implode(" + ", $fields) . ") * 10 AS score";
```

You can then also shorten the code to generate your WHERE clause:

```
foreach ($fields as $f) {
  $where .= " AND {$f} = 1";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I can't seem to get this example to work but I will look into this.